# Plotting Curvature of r(t)={2cost,3sint,0}

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the curvature of the cure r(t)={2cost,3sint,0} where t is at or between 0 and 2pi.

Based on other examples, I tried:

```
r[t_] := {2cos[t], 3sin[t], 0}
Simplify@ArcCurvature[r[t], t]
Plot[%, {t, 0, 6.2832}]
ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 6.2832}]
```

But I was not getting anything in my graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suppose to use `Cos` and `Sin` starting with a capital letters not `cos` and `sin`.

```
r[t_] := {2 Cos[t], 3 Sin[t], 0}
```

Whenever you are getting empty plot, try to input some numerical values to your expression to see what you are getting.

What I meant to say is, lets use your expression which has wrong syntax,

```
r[t_] := {2 cos[t], 3 sin[t], 0}
```

Now plugin a numerical value for `t`,

```
N[r[1]]
```

> {2. cos[1.], 3. sin[1.], 0.}

You can clearly, see that the output is not a list of numbers just expression.

If I do this for my expression, I get,

> {1.0806, 2.52441, 0.}

Comment: It worked! thank you so much!!